# Pass Dynamic Javascript Variable to Django/Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have looked at a number of answers and other websites, but none answer my specific question. I have a webpage with "+" and "-" buttons, which should increment a variable called "pieFact". This variable must be updated dynamically without having to refresh the page. It should then be passed to my Django view each time the value is changed. This will be used to update the size of pie charts in a web map. I have the following:

```
<button type="button" id=bttnMinus onclick="pieFact=pieFact*0.9">-</button>
<button type="button" id=bttnPlus onclick="pieFact=pieFact*1.1">+</button></td> 
<script type="text.javascript">
    var pieFact=0;
</script>
```

How can I pass the value of "pieFact" to Django? Based on my limited knowledge, I think I may have to use AJAX post/get.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to keep from refreshing the page, yes, you will need AJAX. I usually don't like to suggest libraries too much in answers, however, in the interest of being easily cross-browser compatible, I would suggest the use of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

### With jQuery it would be as simple as

#### Inside of your django template

```
<html>
    ...
    <head>
        <script>
            var URL = "{% url 'my_view_that_updates_pieFact' %}";
        </script>
    </head>
...
```

#### Later on...

You'll need to either POST or GET the data to the server via AJAX. To be more RESTful, whenever I need to send data to the server I use POST. jQuery provides the [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) convenience function to AJAX data to a url via POST. The three parameters are the URL, the data to send (as a JavaScript object; think python dictionaries if you're not too familiar with JavaScript), and a callback function once the server sends back a response.

```
<script>
function updatePieFact(){
    var data = {'pieFact': pieFact};
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
        else{ alert('Error! :('); }
    });
}
```

The `.click()` functions are basically the same thing as specifying `onlick` in the html attribute. Both click events update `pieFact` as you would expect and then call `updatePieFact()` to send the value of `pieFact` to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bttnMinus').click(function(){
        pieFact *= 0.9;
        updatePieFact();
    });
    $('#bttnPlus').click(function(){
        pieFact *= 1.1;
        updatePieFact();
    });
});
</script>
```

#### In views.py

Since I've used the `$.post()` function in the JavaScript, the request that Django is going to receive is going to have a method of `"POST"`, so I check to make sure that the method is indeed `POST` (this means that if someone visits the URL for this view with something like a GET request, they won't update anything). Once I see that the request is, in fact, a `POST`, I check to see if the key `'pieFact'` is in the dict `request.POST`.

Remember when I set the variable `data` in the javascript to `{'pieFact': pieFact}`? That javascript just becomes the request.POST python dictionary. So, if in the javascript I had instead used `var data = {'hello': pieFact};`, then I would be checking `if 'hello' in request.POST` instead. Once I see that `pieFact` is in the request.POST dictionary, I can get its value and then do something with it. If everything is successful, I return an `HttpResponse` with the string `'success'`. This correlates with the check in javascript: `if(response === 'success')`.

```
def my_view_that_updates_pieFact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'pieFact' in request.POST:
            pieFact = request.POST['pieFact']
            # doSomething with pieFact here...
            return HttpResponse('success') # if everything is OK
    # nothing went well
    return HttpRepsonse('FAIL!!!!!')
```

Hopefully that will get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. This was extremely helpful! It fails on the check: "if 'pieFact' in request.POST:". 'pieFact' appears to be in data so I'm not sure why it's erroring.

Comment: For debugging purposes, you could `print request.POST` to see what *is* in the `POST` dict. Also, check your console or network log on your browser to see what the browser is sending to the server.

Comment: I have a button on the page, which submits an html form. Nothing shows up as posted until I click that button. All my other variables show up in the form list as posted except 'pieFact'. Nothing seems to happen when I press 'minus' or 'plus' buttons.

Comment: jQuery is properly configured and my url is working correctly for $.post.

Comment: Just to make sure, your button IDs above are shown without quotes, are they quoted in the actual html? Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your html and javascript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7XVur/1/ . I corrected the quotes and it still doesn't run. There are a number of external relations with database and map files so the site doesn't function through jsfiddle.

Comment: Make sure that `var pieFact = <some initial value>;` is placed somewhere. Also, you want `var URL = "{% url 'view' %}";` to be inside of the Django template within `<script>` tags, *not* in the javascript itself. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7XVur/2/

Comment: In the network log (on Google Chrome), it shows the posted page correctly in "preview". When I open it in a new window though, the base page is shown (i.e. no form submitted). The code doesn't line up between the two and I can't figure out how to actually post the updated page back. Any ideas?

Comment: How can I increment a models value? I have a model with item, and it has `quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)`. How can I update this with an increment and decrement button and save the new value to the database?