# pass javascript variable dynamic to python

Tags: jquery, python, variables, dynamic

i hope you can help me with a problem, im not really deep into python or javascript and need some help with the following Project, i tried out the offered solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152420/pass-dynamic-javascript-variable-to-django-python) but I'm stuck right now...

### Project

I'm hosting a Webinterface on my Raspberry Pi, in this Webinterface i included a colorpicker with Javascript. Now i want to send send the RGB-values to a python script. In this Script i want to request these values and use them for controlling a RGB-LED Strip (the controlling part works).

### Problem

My Problem is the communication between Javascript and Python, i don't get Python to request the values. Im using Jquery referring to the description i mentioned at the beginning.

### Working until now

- i get the RGB Values seperated out of the colorpicker
- I can see in the Chrome-Browser, that my Webpage is sending data to my python script

## Code:

#### Webinterface

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#picker').colpick({

flat:true,
layout:'hex',
submit:0,
   colorScheme: 'dark',
   onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor){
var rdata= {'rcolor' :rgb.r};
var gdata= {'gcolor' :rgb.g};
var bdata= {'bcolor' :rgb.b};
$.post("/led.py",rdata);
$.post("/led.py",gdata);
$.post("/led.py",bdata);
}

});
```

#### Pythonscript

```
def rgb_data(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'rcolor' in request.POST:
        rcolor = request.POST['rcolor']
        setLights(RED_PIN, rcolor)
    if 'gcolor' in request.POST:
        gcolor = request.POST['gcolor']
        setLights(GREEN_PIN, gcolor)
    if 'gcolor' in request.POST:
        brcolor = request.POST['bcolor']
        setLights(BLUE_PIN, bcolor)
```

Comment: Are you running a webserver with some support for executing Python? What is your environment? Django? What happens when you try and run what you have?

Comment: what you are getting `print(request.POST)` ?

Comment: @ Lattyware:
The webserver is hosted with apache2. The OS of the raspberry pi is raspbian, python is preinstalled, but i don't really know which environment... When i just run the script with "python led.py" (where led.py is the name of scirpt) nothing happens, so it seems like there are no syntax errors

Comment: @ itzmeontv: I have to say that i don't really know how to get the printout: If i just add it to my python script and run it the variable request.POST doesn't exist because i'm not running the javascript at this moment. But even if i use the javascript there's nothing printed out to my terminal