# Cannot pass JavaScript variable to Django View.py

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a JavaScript function that will get the user input and store it into an array called `tableData`. I want the `tableData` value in javascript to be use in Django `view.py`.

I had tried to use AJAX and `post method` to send my `tableData`. But whenever i clicked on `submit` it show me `error`.

[image]

**Html template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <html>
    <head>
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,500"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <style>
        .buttonSubmit {
          background-color: #4caf50;
          border: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 15px 32px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 16px;
          margin: 4px 2px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .del_img {
          background-color: Transparent;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          overflow: hidden;
          outline: none;
        }

        table {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        body {
          font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
        }
        .button {
          border-radius: 50px;
          background-color: #ff9633;
          border: none;
          color: #ffffff;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 15px;
          padding: 10px;
          width: 80px;
          transition: all 0.5s;
          cursor: pointer;
          margin: 5px;
          margin-left: 500px;
        }

        .button span {
          cursor: pointer;
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .button span:after {
          content: "\00bb";
          position: absolute;
          opacity: 0;
          top: 0;
          right: -20px;
          transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .button:hover span {
          padding-right: 25px;
        }

        .button:hover span:after {
          opacity: 1;
          right: 0;
        }

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
          display: none; /* Hidden by default */
          position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
          z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
          padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%; /* Full width */
          height: 100%; /* Full height */
          overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
          background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
          position: relative;
          background-color: #fefefe;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 0;
          border: 1px solid #888;
          width: 45%;

          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
            0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
          -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
          animation-name: animatetop;
          animation-duration: 0.4s;
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
          from {
            top: -300px;
            opacity: 0;
          }
          to {
            top: 0;
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }

        @keyframes animatetop {
          from {
            top: -300px;
            opacity: 0;
          }
          to {
            top: 0;
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
          color: white;
          float: right;
          font-size: 28px;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
          color: #000;
          text-decoration: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-header {
          padding: 2px 16px;
          background-color: #ff9633;
          color: white;
        }

        .modal-body {
          padding: 2px 16px;
        }

        .modal-footer {
          padding: 2px 16px;
          background-color: #ff9633;
          color: white;
        }

        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #ff9633;
        }

        li {
          float: left;
        }

        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
          background-color: #fa7d34;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="myBtn1"><a href="#AddCon">Alert Policies</a></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Test4</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Alert Policies</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p style="font-size: 14px">
              Please select an event parameter as well as the condition type and
              value that apply.
            </p>

            <!-- parameter drop down -->
            <form method="post">
              <label for="Parameter">
                <b style="font-size: 13px">
                  Event parameter to evaluate
                </b></label
              >
              <select
                name="Parameter"
                id="Parameter"
                style="width: 340px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif"
              >
                <option disabled selected value>select a parameter</option>
                <option value="Subject">Subject</option>
                <option value="Text">Text</option>
              </select>
              <br /><br />

              <label for="Condition">
                <b style="font-size: 13px"> Type of condition </b></label
              >
              <select
                name="Condition"
                id="Condition"
                style="
                  width: 340px;
                  margin-left: 69px;
                  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                "
              >
                <option disabled selected value>select a condition</option>
                <option value="Equals">Equals</option>
                <option value="Contain">Contain</option>
                <option value="NotContain">Does not contain</option>
              </select>
              <br /><br />

              <label for="valuetomatch">
                <b style="font-size: 13px"> Value to match</b></label
              >
              <input
                type="text"
                id="valuetomatch"
                name="valuetomatch"
                style="
                  width: 333px;
                  margin-left: 80px;
                  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                "
              />
              <br />
              <br />
            </form>
            <button class="button"><span>OK</span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <th>Event Parameter</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
          <th>Value to match</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />

      <button id="buttonSubmit">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
  <script>
    var URL = {% url 'test' %};
//declare the array as a global

var tableData = [];
var data = {'tDsend': tableData, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' };


$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").on("click", function () {
    para = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
    condi = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
    value2match = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;

    if (para && condi && value2match !== null) {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

      cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
      cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
      cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;
      cell4.innerHTML =
        '<button  class = "del_img "onClick="delSpec(this)"><img src="deleteimg.png" width="30" height="30"></button> </div>';

      var myTab = document.getElementById("myTable");

      // Only add the new row:
      tableData.push([
        document.getElementById("Parameter").value,
        document.getElementById("Condition").value,
        document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value
      ]);

      modal.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      alert("All the input box cannot be empty!");
    }
  });

document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").onclick = function () {
        alert(tableData);
         $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
        else{ alert('Error! :('); }
    });

      };
});

function delSpec(node) {
  let r = node.parentNode.parentNode;
  tableData.splice(r.rowIndex - 1, 1);
  r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
}
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
</script>
```

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
import email
import imaplib
import mailbox
import smtplib

def index(request):

    return render(request,'DemoApp/hi.html')

def send(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'tdSend' in request.POST:
            pieFact = request.POST['tdSend']
            # doSomething with pieFact here...
            return HttpResponse('success')  # if everything is OK
        # nothing went well
    return HttpResponse('FAIL!!!!!')
    return render(request, 'DemoApp/hi.html', {'key': "Send successfully"})
```

**Url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='home-page'),
    path('send/', views.send, name='test'),

]
```

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152420/pass-dynamic-javascript-variable-to-django-python) tutorial on implementing the AJAX.

I checked the `request.is_ajax()` it return me `False`
[image]

```
    output = request.is_ajax()
    return HttpResponse(output)
    return render(request, 'DemoApp/hi.html', {'key': "Send successfully"})
```

Comment: Check your browser console and network tab for error logs.

Comment: @xyres it show nothing on console , but it show `FAIL!!` on my network tab

Comment: Try to check request.is_ajax() results in true..

Comment: And print request.POST then edit the post with updated details

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ I cant even get into the view.py `/send` function and check the ajax request because it already error on the javascript

Comment: Then please show the console

Comment: Use `debugger` on the JS side and pdb on the python side. Always use the debugger modules while testing things like this. Don't just assume it'll work flawlessly once you wrote the code.
On JS, just type debugger to any line. On Python, add this line to your view. "`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`"

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ I edit my post with the `request.is_ajax`, it return me `False` tho.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın alright thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: @albertlim then the problem is in html and js (ajax)

Comment: @albertlim please refer this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Answer (score 2):

adding to other answers:

You are writing to:
`var data = {'tDsend': tableData, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' };`
while checking:
`if 'tdSend' in request.POST:`.

Give variables sensible names & enable spelling, this will lower the risk of such typos.

Comment: @albert Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your url in double quotes;

```
var URL = "{% url 'test' %}";
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: @EPaul you mean console errors on my browser? It show nothing on my browser console